# pip install tensorflow fails - MAC OSError: [Errno 13]

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow on mac Sierra. When I run `pip install tensorflow` I get following report.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me by using command :

```
pip3 install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.10.1-py3-none-any.whlrflow-1.10.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

run `sudo pip install tensorflow`

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be, that you have not got the rights to install tensorflow globally. Therefore, one solution appears to be, that you try to install tensorflow locally using the following command:

`pip install tensorflow --user`